# To load a raster layer in ArcMap with the C# application

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have a Python script which import a layer in ArcMap, when I execute it in Python console of ArcMap  but now I have to perform the same work with  C# program.
Python script for importing a raster layer is as:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import *
arcpy.env.workspace ="D:/Data/Old_Data"
raster_filename ="output.tif"
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(raster_filename, "tmpLyr")
```

Can creating a toolbox for the script help for this?

Answer (score 1):

This can very easily be accomplished using C#. Depending on your version of ArcGIS Desktop you will need to download a specific version of Visual Studio then the ArcObjects for .Net framework.

I am unsure that a toolbox is the same as using C#.

If you do end up using C# then this might help you.

```
 IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer();
 rasterLayer.CreateFromFilePath(filePath);
 _mxdocument.AddLayer(rasterLayer);
```

Then you are going to want to refresh to show changes in the active view

```
_mxdocument.ActivatedView.Refresh();
```